# My color selector isnt working with my canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have tried to add in a color selector for my drawing app, The color selector works fin but when i draw it just appears in black. Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/daniel9000/egpr99k9/20/)

You can see if you click on the right hand side of my toolbar is the color picker and you will see that the color picker works perfectly but when you select a color it will not draw as the color, If you find a solution please update the JSFiddle and link it so a can go through it and analyse.

my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="SiteIcon.ico">
        <title>Canvas</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function processData(c1, c2) {
                var cv1 = document.getElementById(c1).value;
                var cv2 = document.getElementById(c2).value;
                alert(cv1 + "\n" + cv2);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<span style="cursor:crosshair">
<body style='margin: 0'>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div id="rad">
            Radius <span id="radval">10</span>

    <div id="decrad" class="radcontrol">-</div>
    <div id="incrad" class="radcontrol">+</div> <a href="../Be Creative.html"><font color="white">BACK</font></a>
    <a href="Canvas.html"><font color="white">CLEAR</font></a>

    </div>
    <div id="colors">
        Colour:
            <input type="color" name="color1" id="color1" />
            <br />
            <br />
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="display: block;">sorry, your browser does not support our canvas tag.</canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="toolbar.js"></script>
    <script src="pallet.js"></script>
    </span>
    <br>
    </body>

</html>
```

my css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
}
#toolbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    color: white;
}
.radcontrol {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
#rad {
    float: left;
}
#colors {
    float: right;
}
.swatch {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.swatch.active {
    border: 2px solid white;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#back {
    width: 60px;
    height: 5px;
    padding: 5%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

my javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;
var dragging = false;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

context.lineWidth = radius * 2;

var putPoint = function (e) {
    if (dragging) {
        var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left;
        var mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
        var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left - 20;
        context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY)
        context.stroke();
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        context.fill();
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}

var engage = function (e) {
    dragging = true;
    putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function () {
    dragging = false;
    context.beginPath();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);

var setRadius = function (newRadius) {
    if (newRadius < minRad) newRadius = minRad;
    else if (newRadius > maxRad) newRadius = maxRad;
    radius = newRadius;
    context.lineWidth = radius * 2;

    radSpan.innerHTML = radius;
}

var minRad = 1,
    maxRad = 100,
    defaultRad = 20,
    interval = 5,
    radSpan = document.getElementById('radval'),
    decRad = document.getElementById('decrad'),
    incRad = document.getElementById('incrad');

decRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setRadius(radius - interval);
});
incRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setRadius(radius + interval);
});

setRadius(defaultRad);
```

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
 — don't edit the question text to say it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CJ_/egpr99k9/22/

You need to define a strokeStyle and fillStyle in order to change the colour drawn to canvas (see below). The colour input dom element won't automatically change the colour for you, you need to fetch it through **document.getElementById('color1').value**.

```
var putPoint = function (e) {
    if (dragging) {
      var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left;
      var mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
      var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left - 20;
      context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY)
      context.strokeStyle = document.getElementById('color1').value;
      context.stroke();
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      context.fillStyle = document.getElementById('color1').value;
      context.fill();
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    }
}
```